# Passing arguments to decorator function

Tags: python, python-decorators

Can anyone tell me how to pass argument to a decorator calling function?

```
def doubleIt(Onefunc):
    def doubleIn():
        return Onefunc()*Onefunc()
    return doubleIn

@doubleIt
def Onefunc():  
    return 5

print(Onefunc()) # it prints out 25.
```

However when I try to upgrade my `Onefunc()` to:

```
@doubleIt
def Onefunc(x):
    return x
```

I am facing below error:

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-6e2b55c94c06> in <module>()
      9 
     10 
---> 11 print(Onefunc(5))
     12 

TypeError: doubleIn() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Error is self explanatory, but I am not sure how to update `doubleIn()` function to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also pass an argument in `doubleIn()` function if you set an argument in `Onefunc()`:

```
def doubleIt(Onefunc):
    def doubleIn(x):
        return Onefunc(x)*Onefunc(x)
    return doubleIn

@doubleIt
def Onefunc(x):
    return x

print(Onefunc(5))
```

Comment: I think you should comment if you request for more information.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi: No, this is the working code and it **is** an answer.

Comment: Sorry; I misunderstood your first expression!

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass in the optional positional and keywords arguments.

```
from functools import wraps

def doubleIt(Onefunc):

    @wraps(Onefunc)
    def doubleIn(*args, **kwargs):
        return Onefunc(*args, **kwargs) * Onefunc(*args, **kwargs)
    return doubleIn

@doubleIt
def Onefunc(x):
    return x

print(Onefunc(5))
```

Comment: This is the most common, robust, and (usually) Pythonic way.

Comment: @Afiz, it is not only "also working", it works as well in your first example, while the other one doesn't.